# Trying to use update query to only update fields that are blank in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, criteria

I am trying to use an update query to update fields from one table to another for fields but only if the fields in the table that i am updating into is blank. If they contain information, I do not want to overwrite the existing data

e.g

Field: Name
Table: Table 1
Update to: [Table2.][Name]
Criteria:

I am unsure of what to put in the criteria. I tried, 'Is Null', Like "".

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

UPDATE MyTable SET MyTable.FieldB = "MyNewValue" WHERE (((MyTable.FieldB) Is Null));

Comment: this is in Microsoft Access, the answer you have given looks like a SQL Command?

Comment: While you are looking at the Query from within Access, you can switch to SQL view. You just need to put Is Null in the criteria column.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the Query from within Access, you can switch to SQL view. You just need to put Is Null in the criteria column: UPDATE MyTable SET MyTable.FieldB = "MyNewValue" WHERE (((MyTable.FieldB) Is Null));

Furthermore, you can just write Is Null on alternate lines and it will count as OR.